# Падает программа написанная на С++ (QT Creator 5.9.0) при выполнении POST запроса с использованием JSON

Tags: c++, json, qt

В общем, получаю ошибку:

```
json:  "{\n    \"email\": \"123@mail.ru\",\n    \"login\": \"123\",\n    \"password\": \"123\"\n}\n"
11:02:25: Программа неожиданно завершилась.
11:02:25: Процесс был завершён принудительно.
11:02:25: D:/Documents/Qt/1 prototype/build-prototype-Desktop_Qt_5_9_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/debug/prototype аварийно завершился.
```

В следующем файле (registration.cpp):

```
#include "registration.h"
#include "ui_registration.h"
#include <QRegExp>
#include <qdebug.h>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonDocument>



registration::registration(QWidget *parent, QString *ipHost) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::registration),
    mailvalidator(QRegExp("^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]{1,}@[a-z]{1,}.[a-z]{,3}$"))
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    this->ipHost = ipHost;
    this->ipHost->insert(this->ipHost->size(),"/user/registration");
    qDebug()<<"ipHost registration "<<*(this->ipHost);

    ui->text->setText("");
    connect(ui->pass1, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(check()));
    connect(ui->pass2, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(check()));
    ui->email->setValidator(&mailvalidator);
}

registration::~registration()
{
    delete ui;
}

void registration::check(){
    if(ui->pass1->text()==ui->pass2->text()){
        QPixmap chec(":/photo/check.ico");
        ui->foto->setPixmap(chec);
        ui->foto->setScaledContents(true);
        ui->text->setText("");
    }
    else {
        QPixmap cros(":/photo/cross.ico");
        ui->foto->setPixmap(cros);
        ui->foto->setScaledContents(true);
        ui->text->setText(" ! Пароли не совпадают.");
    }
}

void registration::on_go_clicked()
{
    QJsonObject json;
    json.insert("login",    ui->login->text());
    json.insert("password", ui->pass2->text());
    json.insert("email",    ui->email->text());

    qDebug()<<"json: "<<QJsonDocument(json).toJson();
/*
    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl(*(this->ipHost)));
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "json");
    //qDebug()<<manager->post(request, QJsonDocument(json).toJson());
*/
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager->post(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(*(this->ipHost))), QJsonDocument(json).toJson());
    qDebug()<<reply;
    while(!reply->isFinished()){
        qDebug()<<"ВСё завершилось)";
    }
    QByteArray response_data = reply->readAll();
    QJsonDocument jsonresponse = QJsonDocument::fromJson(response_data);
    reply->deleteLater();


    //тут запрос для создания нового пользователя
}
```

Прикладываю еще код (registration.h)

```
#ifndef REGISTRATION_H
#define REGISTRATION_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QRegExpValidator>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonParseError>
#include <QStandardItem>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>

namespace Ui {
class registration;
}

class registration : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit registration(QWidget *parent = nullptr, QString *ipHost = nullptr);
    ~registration();

    QString *ipHost;
    QNetworkAccessManager* manager;

private slots:
    void check();


    void on_go_clicked();

private:
    Ui::registration *ui;
    QRegExpValidator mailvalidator;

};

#endif // REGISTRATION_H
```

На всякий случай приложу и pro-файл:

```
QT += core gui sql network

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = prototype
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp \
    login_window.cpp \
    adddata.cpp \
    registration.cpp \
    setting.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h \
    login_window.h \
    adddata.h \
    registration.h \
    setting.h

LIBS += -L"D:/Program Files/Qt/5.9/openssl"
        -lqjson

INCLUDEPATH += "D:/Program Files/Qt/5.9/openssl/include"

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui \
    login_window.ui \
    adddata.ui \
    registration.ui \
    setting.ui

RESOURCES += \
    resourse.qrc
```

Вся проблема, на мой взгляд, с выполнением запроса:

```
manager->post(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(*(this->ipHost))), QJsonDocument(json).toJson());
```

Потому что ошибка, приведенная первой в вопросе, появляется во время выполнения данного кода, так как никаких записей из qDebug() в консоль не делается, которые идут сразу после данного кода...

Может кто работал с json в QT и может подсказать.

Comment: Зачем вы указали версию QtCreator? Она никак не связана с версией компилятора и Qt. По теме: запустите код в отладчике, благо QtCreator с ним дружит. У меня вызывает подозрение `ipHost`: в подобных случаях передача по сырому указателю чего-либо, кроме наследников `QObject` - плохая идея, а у вас при этом `ipHost = nullptr` по умолчанию, но нет проверки на нулевой указатель в коде.

Comment: Где manager инициализируется/создается?

Comment: Где инициализируется manager?

Comment: Запусти дебагер, он при падении укажет на место падения

Comment: @Ariox, во-первых, `ipHost` никак не `nullptr`, но это я не указал в вопросе, ладно. Скажу лишь, что адрес там вполне корректный.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, Спасибо, я уже исправил этот момент, добавил инициализацию. От этого и перестала "падать" программа, но, к сожалению, на сервер так и не приходит информация.

Comment: Проверяйте правильность адреса и порта отправки сообщения. Что тут еще можно посоветовать?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, скажите пожалуйста, а по самому запросу json есть какие-нибудь вопросы? Он написан корректно? Может что забыл прописать и из-за этого на сервер ничего не приходит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, кому может поможет.
Следующий код сработал вполне корректно (registration.cpp):

```
#include "registration.h"
#include "ui_registration.h"
#include <QRegExp>
#include <qdebug.h>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonDocument>



registration::registration(QWidget *parent, QString *ipHost) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::registration),
    mailvalidator(QRegExp("^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]{1,}@[a-z]{1,}.[a-z]{,3}$"))
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    this->ipHost = ipHost;
    this->ipHost->insert(this->ipHost->size(),"/user/registration");
    qDebug()<<"ipHost registration "<<*(this->ipHost);

    ui->text->setText("");
    connect(ui->pass1, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(check()));
    connect(ui->pass2, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(check()));
    ui->email->setValidator(&mailvalidator);
}

registration::~registration()
{
    delete ui;
}

void registration::check(){
    if(ui->pass1->text()==ui->pass2->text()){
        QPixmap chec(":/photo/check.ico");
        ui->foto->setPixmap(chec);
        ui->foto->setScaledContents(true);
        ui->text->setText("");
    }
    else {
        QPixmap cros(":/photo/cross.ico");
        ui->foto->setPixmap(cros);
        ui->foto->setScaledContents(true);
        ui->text->setText(" ! Пароли не совпадают.");
    }
}

void registration::on_go_clicked()
{
    QJsonObject json;
    json.insert("login",    ui->login->text());
    json.insert("password", ui->pass2->text());
    json.insert("email",    ui->email->text());

    qDebug()<<"json: "<<QJsonDocument(json).toJson();

    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl(*(this->ipHost)));
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QByteArray jsonData= QJsonDocument(json).toJson();
    qDebug()<<"jsonData: "<<jsonData;

    manager->post(request, jsonData);
}
```

Comment: Этот код позволит лишь отправить post-запрос с использованием json, пока не удалось корректно прочитать ответ и что-нибудь с ответом сделать. (пока учусь работать с json)